# Slick slider: Image size issue on page load

Tags: slider, banner-slider, slick, loading

I added CSS so first slide show up with other elements, but I think the image shows up with the original size and then working perfectly when page load up completely.

My css:

```
.home-slider-wrapper .item  {
    display: none;
}

.home-slider-wrapper .item:first-child  {
    display: block;
}

.home-slider-wrapper .slick-initialized .item {
    display: block;
}
```

My slider:

```
<div class="home-slider-wrapper">
<div id="header_slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
<?php foreach ($bannerCollection as $banner): ?>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="<?php echo ($banner->getBannerLink()) ? $banner->getBannerLink() : "#"; ?>">
            <img class="desktop-image" src="<?php echo $baseUrl.$banner->getDesktopImg(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner->getBannerTitle(); ?>">
            <img class="mobile-image" src="<?php echo $baseUrl.$banner->getMobileImg(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner->getBannerTitle(); ?>">
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'slickSlider'
], function ($) {
    $("#header_slider").slick({
        dots: true,
        autoplay: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slideswToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true
    });
});
```

I am adding screenshot for more understanding,
during page load:
[image]

after loading:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but this worked for me in a similar situation on my site. You can use CSS for this.

```
.your-slider-class{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.your-slider-class.slick-initialized {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

Hope this helps someone who facing the same issue.